# Parsing Google news in Java

Tags: java, parsing

What is the best way to do that?

I want to parse the news and, then, filter them using something like keyword and find the match.

Someone has already done? And, it is lawful?

Comment: This is too general of a question for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use rss feeds of google news url http://news.google.com/?output=rss it will return google rss news in the rss tag with html tags. Then either write custom code to read/parse the xml or using any existing RSS reading library like https://github.com/vgrec/SimpleRssReader

Answer (score 0):

I have written a function to accomplish this which will return link and title of the random news each time.

```
public Document getNews() {
    Document news = new Document();
    URL rssUrl = null;
    try {
        rssUrl = new URL("https://news.google.com/rss");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    DocumentBuilder builder = null;
    try {
        builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    org.w3c.dom.Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = builder.parse(rssUrl.openStream());
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    NodeList items = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
    Element item = (Element) items.item(new Random().nextInt(items.getLength()));
    news.append("title", getValue(item, "title"));
    news.append("link", getValue(item, "link"));
    return news;
}

private String getValue(Element parent, String nodeName) {
    return parent.getElementsByTagName(nodeName).item(0).getFirstChild().toString();
}
```